# How to select the past 4 full weeks of data (Sunday through Saturday)?

Tags: mysql

Previously I had the query set to grab the last 4 weeks but it didn't count full weeks which threw off Excel pivot tables dependent on the queried data.

I changed it to this and now it's curtailing my data to the last 2 weeks only.

I suspect the AND statement is faulty. Can someone confirm?

```
WHERE
    BalanceDay >= DATE(CONVERT_TZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'UTC', Mapping.DEFAULT_TIMEZONE) - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 1 DAY - INTERVAL 4 WEEK)
    AND BalanceDay <=  DATE(CONVERT_TZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'UTC', Mapping.DEFAULT_TIMEZONE) - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 1 DAY - INTERVAL 3 WEEK) + INTERVAL 6 DAY
```

This is what I had previously which did pull 4 weeks but didn't pull in *full* weeks (i.e. if it ran on a Friday, I would get something other than 28 days' worth of data):

```
WHERE
    BalanceDay >= CONVERT_TZ(CURRENT_DATE, 'UTC', Mapping.DEFAULT_TIMEZONE) -  INTERVAL 4 WEEK
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't understand the real business of your query. but after running it, this query got the last four weeks:

```
WHERE
BalanceDay >= DATE(CONVERT_TZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'UTC', Mapping.DEFAULT_TIMEZONE) - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 1 DAY - INTERVAL 4 WEEK)
AND DATE(CONVERT_TZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '+00:00', '+03:00') - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) + INTERVAL 6 DAY
```

consider using DATE_ADD & DATE_SUB though.

good luck :)